# Simulate BASH arrow to get previous command

Tags: c, bash

I'm not asking how to catch the key stroke, based on an internet search I believe this can be done using the Ncurses library https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

What I want to know is how to display the command in the terminal after I press the key.

Currently I'm trying to replicate part of BASH, what my code does is

```
stephen@stephen:~/project/simsh$ ./simsh.c
stephen@stephen:~/project/simsh$ pwd
whateverDirectoryI'mNowIn
stephen@stephen:~/project/simsh$
```

What I want is it can shows the following after I press the Up-Arrow

```
stephen@stephen:~/project/simsh$ pwd
```

instead of

```
stephen@stephen:~/project/simsh$ ^[[A
```

While I know how to capture the key signal, I don't know how to show the older command out immediately and see it as potential input command.

Comment: Are you wanting to simulate a keystroke or to have a similar type of prompt with history in your application?  If you are making a shell of sorts and want the same functionality, you should accept John K's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [GNU Readline library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) and it'll handle all of this for you.

> GNU Readline is a software library that provides line-editing and history capabilities for interactive programs with a command-line interface, such as Bash. It is currently maintained by Chet Ramey as part of the GNU Project.
>
> It allows users to move the text cursor, search the command history, control a kill ring (a more flexible version of a copy/paste clipboard) and use tab completion on a text terminal. As a cross-platform library, readline allows applications on various systems to exhibit identical line-editing behavior.

Comment: while this is a perfectly satisfying answer, I would like to know how to reinvent the wheel a little

Comment: @StephenFong If you want to write your own lightweight readline, curses would probably be the easiest thing to work with for it.  You could use curses to pick up the keystroke and prevent it from being "printed" as escape codes or whatever, and you could use curses also to do the command editing that you are probably wanting.  FWIW, I'm pretty sure that bash actually uses GNU Readline for this, and it would probably be the best thing to do in my opinion as well.

Comment: IIRC correctly, Readline started its existence as the built-in command-line editor in `bash`, and was later extracted as a separate library. The two are still developed in parallel.